# Passing array by refence in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to learn Angular 5, I created a sample project (Blog where I display posts), here the service for the posts:

```
export class PostService {

posts = [
        {
          title: "Post 1",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
        {
          title: "Post 2",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
        {
          title: "Post 3",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
    ];

getPosts() {
    return this.posts;
}

setLoveItsToDefault() {
    for (let post of this.posts) {
        post.loveIts = 0;
    }
}

initializeLovesPost(i: number) {
    this.posts[i].loveIts = 0;
}
}
```

And in `AppComponent`, I inject the service, and I try to update all posts (if they have more than 1 love/like, then I set it to 0):

```
export class AppComponent {

@Input() posts : Post[];

constructor(private postService: PostService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();
}

onInitializeLoves() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to initialize all loves of all posts to 0 ?')) {
        this.postService.setLoveItsToDefault();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

In the html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onInitializeLoves()">Initialize loves</button><br><br>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <app-post [posts]="posts"></app-post>
        </ul>>
```

Here I use posts (PostListComponent, selector: 'app-post'):

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() posts: Post;
  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }
}
```

The html for this component:

```
<app-post-item *ngFor="let post of posts"
            [postTitle]="post.title"
            [postContent]="post.content"
            [postCreatedAt]="post.created_at"
            [postLoveits]="post.loveIts">
</app-post-item>
```

And here the last component PostListItemComponent who display each post:

```
export class PostListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() postTitle: string;
  @Input() postContent: string;
  @Input() postLoveits: number;
  @Input() postCreatedAt: Date;

  constructor() { }

  getPadding() {
    return '0px';
  }

  onAddLoveIt() {
    this.postLoveits++;
  }

  onAddDontLoveIt() {
    this.postLoveits--;
  }
}
```

Here where I use loves/likes:

```
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item': true, 'list-group-item-success': postLoveits > 0, 'list-group-item-danger': postLoveits < 0}">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': getPadding()}"><h3 class="pull-left">{{ postTitle }}</h3></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><h3 class="pull-right">{{ postCreatedAt | date: 'dd/MM/y h:m' }}</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>{{ postContent }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddLoveIt()">Love it!</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onAddDontLoveIt()">Don't love it!</button>
```

Everything works fine without error, but if the posts have loves/likes, if i do `console.log` then I see they are initialized to 0, but in my page nothing changes, so here I am not sure if I have to render the array again, or to pass it by reference (I know in angular the array is passed by reference by default) ? In the tutorial I am following, he just made the same way I made, and it was working...

### Update

Here a [link](https://github.com/gothiquo/angular-blog.git) for github repository, to see the full code.

Comment: seems like you simply have to re-request the data after update, so you can add `this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();` after the line `this.postService.setLoveItsToDefault();`

Comment: Take a look at Subject and Behavior Subject, they give us the possibility to get changes when they updates: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html

Comment: check updates ;)

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko I already tried it and it doesn't work..

Comment: @MosCH your update method updates static records of service, instead of records which are in your component, you can try to move that method to component class

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko sorry, can you explain more? It is my first contact with Angular and I am lost... I understood that my update method will just update static posts and not posts themselves in the service, then where to move it? which component class?

Comment: services usually don't store the data, they are used for http requests which will bring/send data to/from your components. So when you are triggering `initializeLovesPost` it only affects on the posts which are defined in service's class. In this case you will have to use rxjs approach as @CommercialSuicide mentioned, will post the example in answers

Comment: Either use the observable or make a simple trick like reassign the value inside onInitializeLoves ,   this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();

Comment: @reassign the value doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PostListItemComponent`, the input values are copies of the corresponding `Post` properties:

```
<app-post-item *ngFor="let post of posts"
                [postTitle]="post.title"
                [postContent]="post.content"
                [postCreatedAt]="post.created_at"
                [postLoveits]="post.loveIts">
</app-post-item>
```

```
export class PostListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() postTitle: string;
  @Input() postContent: string;
  @Input() postLoveits: number;
  @Input() postCreatedAt: Date;
  ...
}
```

Changes to the source data (the items of the array) would update the values in the component, thanks to one-way data binding, but changes to the values in the component will not modify the source data.

Here is what I think happens when you click on the buttons to add/remove a "love" on a post:

- The value of `postLoveIts` is modified in the component
- The source data (the `loveIts` property of the `Post`) remains unchanged
- Due to the data binding, Angular updates `postLoveIts` with the source data
- The view keeps showing the original `post.loveIts` value

---

In order to keep a reference to the item of the `Post` array, and to make sure that any change in the component modifies the source data, you could pass the `Post` itself to the `PostListItemComponent`:

```
<app-post-item *ngFor="let p of posts" [post]="p"></app-post-item>
```

and refer to its properties in code:

```
export class PostListItemComponent {

  @Input() post: Post;

  onAddLoveIt() {
    this.post.loveIts++;
  }

  onAddDontLoveIt() {
    this.post.loveIts--;
  }
}
```

and in the template:

```
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item': true, 'list-group-item-success': post.loveIts > 0, 'list-group-item-danger': post.loveIts < 0}">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6" [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': getPadding()}"><h3 class="pull-left">{{ postTitle }}</h3></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><h3 class="pull-right">{{ post.created_at | date: 'dd/MM/y h:m' }}</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>{{ post.content }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddLoveIt()">Love it!</button> 
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onAddDontLoveIt()">Don't love it!</button>
```

Note: If the `post` input value has any chance of being undefined or null, you can use the safe navigation operator `?.` in the template to avoid runtime errors (e.g. `post?.loveIts > 0`).

---

By the way, the `posts` input property in `PostListComponent` should be defined as an array:

```
@Input() posts: Post[];
```

Comment: Cannot set property posts of [object Object] which has only a getter

Comment: that is what I did ;) but not working, I have the same situation like the first (the array is not updated)

Comment: I see `postLoveits` in your template, but that variable is not defined (from what I can see). I don't know how you retrieve the post items exactly, but if each one is assigned to a `post` template variable (for example, in an `*ngFor` loop), you should replace `postLoveits` with `post.loveIts`.

Comment: no it is defined... sorry the solution doesn't work :(

Comment: Show more of the template. All of it, if possible.

Comment: And add the parts of the code/template where `postLoveits` is defined. That must be somewhat important, since you use it to show the data in the template, but we don't know how it is defined and how it is updated.

Comment: I added all the code, so you have a better overview.

Comment: I updated my answer (strange, I wrote the same comment a few hours ago but it has disappeared).

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick

```
export class PostService {

posts = [
        {
          title: "Post 1",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
        {
          title: "Post 2",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
        {
          title: "Post 3",
          content: "bla bla bla",
          loveIts: 0,
          created_at: new Date,
        },
    ];

getPosts() {
    // check docs about Observables/Subjects, etc
    return Observable.from(this.posts);
}

setLoveItsToDefault() {
    for (let post of this.posts) {
        post.loveIts = 0;
    }
}

initializeLovesPost(i: number) {
    this.posts[i].loveIts = 0;
}
}
```

then in your component

```
export class AppComponent {

posts: any[];

constructor(private postService: PostService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.postService.getPosts()
   .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
}

onInitializeLoves() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to initialize all loves of all posts to 0 ?')) {
        this.postService.setLoveItsToDefault();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

[Observable doc](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Comment: in my service I added `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';` but always I get the error `Observable_1.Observable.from is not a function`

Comment: why do you use `Observable_1`? UPDATE: your import should be like this `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: I dont use `Observable_1` I wrote the same code as you, just I added the import in the head of the page

Comment: I added all the code, so you have a better overview.